# How to change the repo Homebrew is installing from?

Tags: homebrew, macos-big-sur

I uninstalled homebrew once when trying to fix an error but now when I try to re-install it, I keep getting `error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/deadline`.

I looked at several solutions online and I realized this is happening because, for some reason, Homebrew is actually installing from a different repo that I have on my mac instead of from the Homebrew repo.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with help from the Homebrew's discussion page [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1739). The solution was to unset the `remote.origin.url` in my global git config.